# How to prevent Button freeze after first Submit

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.Net and MySQL for my database,I have 4 Textboxes with a different conditional statement,and 1 Button for `Add/insert` to database. This is the name of my TextBoxes for `group1` it is `TextBox_A` and `TextBox_B`, for `group2` it is `TextBox_C` and `TextBox_D`. When I click submit/insert button,At first Condition for `group1` it is correct, and successfully added to database, but my problem is, When I Enter/Fill those `2 TextBoxes`, under `group2` and again when I click `Add/insert` button, then button will freeze and it don't had allowing it to submit, and I don't know what the problem is, and of course I use `open.Connection` and `Close.Connection` at every condition.

By the way this is my code:

```
 Private Sub cmbInsert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbInsert.Click
   If TextBox_A.Text <> "" And TextBox_B <> "" And  TextBox_C.Text ="" And TextBox_D = "" Then

      objconn = New MySqlConnection
      objconn.ConnectionString = "server=xxx; username=xxx; password=xxx; database=xxxx"
      objconn.Open()
            With objcmd
                .Connection = objconn
                .CommandText = "insert query here"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
       objconn.Close()
       MsgBox("Data Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "SUCCESS")

   ElseIf TextBox_C.Text <> "" And TextBox_D <> "" And  TextBox_A.Text ="" And TextBox_B = "" Then

      objconn = New MySqlConnection
      objconn.ConnectionString = "server=xxx; username=xxx; password=xxx; database=xxxx"
      objconn.Open()
            With objcmd
                .Connection = objconn
                .CommandText = "insert query here"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
       objconn.Close()
      MsgBox("Data Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "SUCCESS")

   End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: There are few problems with the wording that make your question a little unclear.  But are you sure the button is freezing?  Is it possible that it's simply not doing anything?  Did you try stepping through the code in Visual Studio?

Comment: By the way it is not freezing sorry, And now I try to run again but the main problem is, it is not allowed to populate at another condition. because what I am done today is, it is also accept inserting record at `group1` or `TextBox_A` and `TextBox_B` boxes. rather

Comment: And it is possible that at second condition it is simply not doing anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can tell that you struggle with english, and that's making it harder to understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things.  First, your conditions don't take into account that all four text boxes could have text, and also if they are going to do similar things, consider breaking that out into reusable methods.

**EDIT:** Could be way simpler than that :)  Just add **.Text**

```
Private Sub cmbInsert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbInsert.Click
   If TextBox_A.Text <> "" And TextBox_B.Text <> "" And  TextBox_C.Text ="" And TextBox_D.Text = "" Then

      objconn = New MySqlConnection
      objconn.ConnectionString = "server=xxx; username=xxx; password=xxx; database=xxxx"
      objconn.Open()
            With objcmd
                .Connection = objconn
                .CommandText = "insert query here"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
       objconn.Close()
       MsgBox("Data Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "SUCCESS")

   ElseIf TextBox_C.Text <> "" And TextBox_D.Text <> "" And  TextBox_A.Text ="" And TextBox_B.Text = "" Then

      objconn = New MySqlConnection
      objconn.ConnectionString = "server=xxx; username=xxx; password=xxx; database=xxxx"
      objconn.Open()
            With objcmd
                .Connection = objconn
                .CommandText = "insert query here"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
       objconn.Close()
      MsgBox("Data Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "SUCCESS")

   End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean? and yes that is couple text boxes.

Comment: Option 1:
A yes
B yes
C no
D no
//
Option 2:
A no
B no
C yes
D yes.

You have nothing that handles what you are doing, where all 4 textboxes contain text (all 4 = yes).

Comment: As to my other point, both "if" statements do the same thing.  Make that a method.  If the query changes based on the text boxes, pass the query as a string to the new method.

Comment: I put another condition for 4 textbox with have a value but it is also the same.

Comment: I didn't realize that sometimes you forgot to put .Text, so you're making sure the object does or doesn't equal an empty string - which is vastly different than checking the contents of the box :)

Comment: Ok. I insert once. at `group1` only but nothing on `group2`. I think my condition will not allowed to do anything except at `group1`. Only at `group1` exists.:)

Comment: TextBox_C.Text <> "" And TextBox_D **.Text** <> "" And  TextBox_A.Text ="" And TextBox_B **.Text** = "" Then